# Не отвечает бот в телеграмме C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Я написал бота который высылает ссылку на группу в телеграмме, но при запуске он не реагирует не на какие команды, он работает через раз. что можно сделать?

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Stripe;
using Stripe.Checkout;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "MY_TOKEN";

            TelegramBotClient tgbot = new TelegramBotClient("MY_TOKEN");
            tgbot.StartReceiving(update, error);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static Task error(ITelegramBotClient arg1, Exception arg2, CancellationToken arg3)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static async Task update(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update updateeee, CancellationToken token)
        {
            Message msg = updateeee.Message;
            long chatId = -941848938;
            string inviteLink = await botClient.ExportChatInviteLinkAsync(chatId);

            var options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
                {
                    "card",
                    "cashapp"
                },
                LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
                {
                    new SessionLineItemOptions
                    {
                        PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
                        {
                            Currency = "usd",
                            UnitAmount = 20000,
                            ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                            {
                                Name = "Проходка в чат",
                                Description = "Получаешь доступ к чату"
                            },
                        },
                        Quantity = 1,
                    },
                },
                Mode = "payment",
                SuccessUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
            };

            var service = new SessionService();
            var session = service.Create(options);

            if (msg.Text != null)
            {
                switch(msg.Text.ToLower())
                {
                    case "/start":
                        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(msg.Chat.Id, "вот твоя ссылка для покупки: " + session.Url);
                        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, $"Вот ваша личная ссылка на вход в чат: {inviteLink}");
                        return;
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: уберите в `error` `throw new NotImplementedException();` для начала и напишитe `Console.WriteLine(arg2.Message); return Task.CompletedTask;`. Возможно у вас возникают ошибки, которые вы не видите. Кстати, названия методов в C# принято писать с большой буквы.